# Java print table with scanner

Tags: java, rows, col

I am trying to print a table with columns through a scanner and rows. Of course, the for loop should start at 0, but I want it to start count by 1 for print out. Please help me correctly print the code. I am getting null and a pyramid of numbers.

```
Output needed when n = 4 inputted:
    1    1    1    1
    2    2    2    2
    3    3    3    3
    4    4    4    4

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Testing {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.print("Type any variable?");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        int n = input.nextInt();

        String[] arr = new String[n + 1];
        String s = "";
        for (int count = 1; count <= 10; count++) {
            for (int col = 1; col <= n; col++) {
                s = count + "\t";
                arr[col] += s;
                System.out.println(arr[col]);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I don't understand your hard-coded `<= 10` ... why 10? Also, do you know the difference between `System.out.println()` and `System.out.print()`? If not, then this is one thing you need to learn for this task, or is at least pretty handy.

Comment: I am using 10 as an example.

Comment: Then the requirements for the output aren't clearly described by you. What would you, for example, expect with the input value of "20"?

Comment: Again, I am using 10 as an example.

Comment: Example of what?

Answer (score 3):

You're close, but you're over complicating the problem. There's no need to store the result in an array, or a buffer string. You can use `print` to write to the screen without making a newline, and at the end of each inner loop, you can use `println` to move to the next line.

```
int n = input.nextInt();
for (int count = 1; count <= n; count++) {
    for (int col = 1; col <= n; col++) {
        System.out.print(count + "\t");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```